# Changing keyboard layout of a laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dell-inspiron, dell-xps

In many Dell laptops, the Home, End, PgUp and PgDn buttons are combined with the arrow keys, so to press one of them you have to press Fn+Arrow; see bottom-right of the figure:

[image]

This is very uncomfortable since I use these keys a lot during programming. Moreover, selecting text with Shift+Home/End/PgUp/PgDn becomes even harder.

Is there any way to change the keyboard layout such that all 8 keys (arrows, home, end, PgUp, PgDn) are independent?

Comment: reading your question its hard to believe you are programmer. how you can modify layout depends on OS you are using, just search for keyboard layout editor for your OS. also as a programmer you can write your own - that's what I have done when original keyboard lack some functionality :)

Comment: what do you mean by "all 8 keys .."? from the picture I see you have only 4 keys. If you want more keys on the keyboard - you can use external numpad or whole keyboard plugged via USB, or buy another laptop which has 8 independent keys. Sorry, but you question is unclear. On Windows you can reprogram keys with Autohotkey. Here on Superuser there is a tag for it, but you should come up with some real question though.